# Is it possible to use SELECT ST_GeomFromText( with other SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I'm trying to use `SELECT ST_GeomFromText()` with a value catched from another query:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
  ST_AsText(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
  SELECT 
    column-name
  FROM table-name
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1)
  ), 
4326);
```

The value that i'm traying to use is compatible with the `SELECT ST_GeomFromText()` and i'm using postgres.

Other solution that would help would be a `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT ST_GeomFromText()` as a value.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311537

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is not needed here.

The query should be:

```
SELECT ST_SETSRID(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(column-name), 
    4326)
FROM table-name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If for other reasons you still want to use the subquery, you can wrap it in parentheses:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
  ST_AsText(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
     (
       SELECT 
         column-name
       FROM table-name
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 1)
     )
  ), 
4326);
```

Comment: I tried both options and they didn't work, and the following error happened: 


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "column"
LINE 2:     ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(column-name), 
                               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 43


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "column"
LINE 6:          column-name
                 ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 93

Comment: you need to write the real column name

Comment: Yes, i did that before running.